# NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined

Tags: python, docker, mysql-connector

I have following errors. I'm using Docker CentOS:latest.
It seems to occur the error on sqlalchemy part.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: cannot allocate memory in static TLS block

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "promotion_to_wis.py", line 107, in <module>
    promotion_update()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "promotion_to_wis.py", line 77, in promotion_update
    engine = Environment(env).get_sa_engine()
  File "/var/www/app/backend/app/batch/config/environment.py", line 52, in get_sa_engine
    engine = create_engine(mysql_conn % ("user", "passwd", "mysql", 3306, "host"))
  File "<string>", line 2, in create_engine
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 298, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 548, in create_engine
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/mysql/mysqldb.py", line 167, in dbapi
    return __import__("MySQLdb")
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    version_info, _mysql.version_info, _mysql.__file__
NameError: name '_mysql' is not defined
```

```
FROM centos:latest

COPY . /var/www/app/

RUN yum update -y --disableplugin=fastestmirror && \
    yum install -y epel-release --disableplugin=fastestmirror && \
    yum install -y --disableplugin=fastestmirror sudo cronie && \
    yum install -y python38 mysql gcc vim wget && \
    yum install -y python38-devel mysql-devel

RUN wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
RUN python3 get-pip.py

WORKDIR /var/www/app/backend

RUN pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org -r requirements.txt
```

```
        mysql_conn = "mysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?charset=utf8"
        engine = create_engine(mysql_conn % ("user", "passwd", "mysql", 3306, "host"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using a Centos image, looks like the `mysql-server` package isn't loading properly; try adding `dnf install mysql-server` to your `RUN`.

That should install `mysql-server` and all of it dependencies.

Comment: I have still same errors. @Erik Caldwell